# Firebase Cloud Messaging not working if on the device there are more than one app bound to a single Firebase Project

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm studying Firebase SDK and I have a single Firebase project to which I bound many apps; all of these apps include Firebase SDK and its functions (for example: login with FB, login with google, realtime Database, Cloud messaging, etc.).

Now I built an app for testing Firebase Cloud Messaging and I saw that the messages sent by Firebase are not delivered to the device if on the device are installed more than one app (for example app1, app2, app3) bound to the same Firebase project (for example myFirebaseProject).

If from the device I remove all the apps (app1, app2, app3) bound to Firebase project (myFirebaseProject) and then I installed only one app (app1) the messages sent from Firebase are correctly delivered.

Does anybody understand why?

Comment: Contact Firebase support a file a bug report if you think FCM is not working as documented.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/